# How to know which row is in edit mode without events in Kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In a Kendo grid, I wanted to know which row in a edited. This is just before the grid changes in grid are committed(because i m doing validation over here).Over here i have a problem that multiple functions are been called so therefore i don't have the event which was present in the first function. As shown below, I get multiple rows in data from which i want to know which row is been updated. I am using Inline mode of Kendo.

```
function updateRow(event) {
    debugger
    $("#errorPaymentDue").hide();
    grid = $("#gridSupplierPaymentDue").data("kendoGrid");
    var index = $(event).closest("tr").index();
    ...
    myfunction1();
    //myfunctionN is call inside many function written inside myfunction1
}
function myfunctionN(){
      var gridValidation = $("#gridSupplierPaymentDue").data("kendoGrid");
      var data = gridValidation.dataSource.data();
      //want to know which row was edited without event
}
```

I know that i can send the index of the specific edited row from functions to functions but this will have multiple function changes and also other code which might be referring this function may also need to be changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get rows that have been updated this way :

```
function myfunctionN() {
   var gridValidation = $("#gridSupplierPaymentDue").data("kendoGrid");
   var data = gridValidation.dataSource.data();
   //want to know which row was edited without event
   //edited data items
   var editedItems = $(data).filter(function() {
        return this.dirty;
   });
   //edited rows
   var editedRows = $(gridValidation.tbody).find("tr").filter(function() {
       return gridValidation.dataSource.getByUid($(this).data("uid")).dirty;
   });
}
```

OR

To get the row that is currently being edited you can do :

```
var rowInEditMode = $("#gridSupplierPaymentDue").find("tr.k-grid-edit-row");
var itemBeingEdited = $("#gridSupplierPaymentDue").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.getByUid(rowInEditMode.data("uid"));
```

Comment: this unfortunately doesn't work if you are using a popup editor.